# average of geometric and harmonic means

Tags: mean, geometric-mean, types-of-averages, harmonic-mean

I have a stochastic simulation model in which three types of mean (arithmetic mean, geometric mean, and harmonic mean) are calculated for three different variables. I run the simulation 1000 times so that at the end I have 1000 values of the three types of mean.

When I show the summary (average) of the 1000 simulation outcomes, is it appropriate to use arithmetic mean for all the three types of mean?

Comment: Can you explain what this statistic would tell us about a sample or population?